# Why doesn't OpenCV findContour method always find closed outer contour?

Tags: opencv, contour

I have two images from the same camera position. The difference between them is that one was taken with orthographic and the other was taken with perspective projection.

Here is the two image:

[image: Perspective and Orthographic sample images]

When I run the **findContour** OpenCV method on them the result is the follwing:

[image]

Why OpenCV doesn't find a closed outer contour curve for the perspective one?

I tried both CV_RETR_TREE and CV_RETR_EXTERNAL flags with the combination of CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE and CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE flags.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) and [sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) (which I am using) for the **findContour** method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I can't reproduce your problem. Try with this code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    RNG rng(1234);

    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat1b bw = ~gray;

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(bw, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(img, contours, i, color, 2);
    }

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Miki, thank you very much for your help. I tried your code and it worked. The difference between your code and mine was that I also blured the image before I called findContour method. I guess for some reason that didn't help for the contour detection.

Comment: You should call `findContours` on a binary (black and white) image. Blurring will produce some intermediate values that probably mess up `findContours`